# Can't resolve `name.first_name` with Faker

Tags: java, faker

I am trying to generate some values for my test.

I try to get all keys from a file.

When I try to generate a first name I got this error:

```
Faker faker = new Faker();
faker.resolve("name.first_name")
```

`Unable to resolve #{male_first_name} directive.`

That is probably because first_name is recursive.

That works fine with `name.last_name`.

Because I want to have key definitions from outside,  I can't call `faker.name().firstName()`

Any Idea?

Comment: "Name.first_name" will work, while as an expression use "#{Name.first_name}" Faker expressions are case sensitive.